# Is it “is” or “are” after “that” in the expression …X of Y that is/are? Context provided in the question

Tags: prepositions, clauses

I am aware of solutions that use "can" or "will" to circumvent the issue, but I really want to know the answer. In the sentence below, "efficacy" is what I want to center on. It is what "that" describes. However, the word "that" immediately follows "gamification mechanics", which got me confused.

Cross-platform comparison of multiple pro-green programs will be a valuable addition to the literature because it helps researchers measure *the efficacy of gamification mechanics that is/are* particularly robust in some situations but not others.

If you have better ways to rewrite the sentence without contorting or undermining the message, please share.

Comment: If you are referring to the efficacy of all gamification mechanics (rather than just those that are particularly robust....... etc), replace **that** with **which**, preceded by a comma.  (See non defining relative clauses) Prefer **is** after **which**.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly - by simplifying the sentence and omitting the reference to literature, while also clarifying that you are talking about **the efficacy**:

Cross-platform comparison of multiple pro-green programs will afford valuable assistance to researchers in measuring the efficacy of gamification mechanics, a feature that is particularly robust in certain situations.

Comment: Ronald: The way you did it definitely flows better than mine. Thank you for that. What if I want to keep the reference to literature?

Comment: Then you have to weigh up the added complexity of lengthening the sentence against the benefit. Alternatively, you might delete the first **valuable** and add :**.....in certain situations, representing a valuable addition to the literature.

Comment: Super! Thanks again.